# How to call Numerical Recipes svdcmp from Julia

Tags: fortran, julia, gfortran

First of all, I know Julia does have an `svd` intrinsic function, but it does not exactly do what I need. Instead, `svdcmp` from Numerical Recipes does.

So, the subroutine is this:

```
  MODULE nrtype
  INTEGER, PARAMETER :: I4B = SELECTED_INT_KIND(9)
  INTEGER, PARAMETER :: I2B = SELECTED_INT_KIND(4)
  INTEGER, PARAMETER :: I1B = SELECTED_INT_KIND(2)
  INTEGER, PARAMETER :: SP = KIND(1.0)
  INTEGER, PARAMETER :: DP = KIND(1.0D0)
  INTEGER, PARAMETER :: SPC = KIND((1.0,1.0))
  INTEGER, PARAMETER :: DPC = KIND((1.0D0,1.0D0))
  INTEGER, PARAMETER :: LGT = KIND(.true.)
  REAL(SP), PARAMETER :: PI=3.141592653589793238462643383279502884197_sp
  REAL(SP), PARAMETER :: PIO2=1.57079632679489661923132169163975144209858_sp
  REAL(SP), PARAMETER :: TWOPI=6.283185307179586476925286766559005768394_sp
  REAL(SP), PARAMETER :: SQRT2=1.41421356237309504880168872420969807856967_sp
  REAL(SP), PARAMETER :: EULER=0.5772156649015328606065120900824024310422_sp
  REAL(DP), PARAMETER :: PI_D=3.141592653589793238462643383279502884197_dp
  REAL(DP), PARAMETER :: PIO2_D=1.57079632679489661923132169163975144209858_dp
  REAL(DP), PARAMETER :: TWOPI_D=6.283185307179586476925286766559005768394_dp
  TYPE sprs2_sp
    INTEGER(I4B) :: n,len
    REAL(SP), DIMENSION(:), POINTER :: val
    INTEGER(I4B), DIMENSION(:), POINTER :: irow
    INTEGER(I4B), DIMENSION(:), POINTER :: jcol
  END TYPE sprs2_sp
  TYPE sprs2_dp
    INTEGER(I4B) :: n,len
    REAL(DP), DIMENSION(:), POINTER :: val
    INTEGER(I4B), DIMENSION(:), POINTER :: irow
    INTEGER(I4B), DIMENSION(:), POINTER :: jcol
  END TYPE sprs2_dp
END MODULE nrtype

MODULE nrutil
    USE nrtype
    IMPLICIT NONE
    INTEGER(I4B), PARAMETER :: NPAR_ARTH=16,NPAR2_ARTH=8
    INTEGER(I4B), PARAMETER :: NPAR_GEOP=4,NPAR2_GEOP=2
    INTEGER(I4B), PARAMETER :: NPAR_CUMSUM=16
    INTEGER(I4B), PARAMETER :: NPAR_CUMPROD=8
    INTEGER(I4B), PARAMETER :: NPAR_POLY=8
    INTEGER(I4B), PARAMETER :: NPAR_POLYTERM=8

    INTERFACE assert_eq
        MODULE PROCEDURE assert_eq2,assert_eq3,assert_eq4,assert_eqn
    END INTERFACE

    INTERFACE outerprod
        MODULE PROCEDURE outerprod_r,outerprod_d
    END INTERFACE

CONTAINS
    FUNCTION assert_eq2(n1,n2,string)
    CHARACTER(LEN=*), INTENT(IN) :: string
    INTEGER, INTENT(IN) :: n1,n2
    INTEGER :: assert_eq2
    if (n1 == n2) then
        assert_eq2=n1
    else
        write (*,*) 'nrerror: an assert_eq failed with this tag:', &
            string
        STOP 'program terminated by assert_eq2'
    end if
    END FUNCTION assert_eq2
!BL
    FUNCTION assert_eq3(n1,n2,n3,string)
    CHARACTER(LEN=*), INTENT(IN) :: string
    INTEGER, INTENT(IN) :: n1,n2,n3
    INTEGER :: assert_eq3
    if (n1 == n2 .and. n2 == n3) then
        assert_eq3=n1
    else
        write (*,*) 'nrerror: an assert_eq failed with this tag:', &
            string
        STOP 'program terminated by assert_eq3'
    end if
    END FUNCTION assert_eq3
!BL
    FUNCTION assert_eq4(n1,n2,n3,n4,string)
    CHARACTER(LEN=*), INTENT(IN) :: string
    INTEGER, INTENT(IN) :: n1,n2,n3,n4
    INTEGER :: assert_eq4
    if (n1 == n2 .and. n2 == n3 .and. n3 == n4) then
        assert_eq4=n1
    else
        write (*,*) 'nrerror: an assert_eq failed with this tag:', &
            string
        STOP 'program terminated by assert_eq4'
    end if
    END FUNCTION assert_eq4
!BL
    FUNCTION assert_eqn(nn,string)
    CHARACTER(LEN=*), INTENT(IN) :: string
    INTEGER, DIMENSION(:), INTENT(IN) :: nn
    INTEGER :: assert_eqn
    if (all(nn(2:) == nn(1))) then
        assert_eqn=nn(1)
    else
        write (*,*) 'nrerror: an assert_eq failed with this tag:', &
            string
        STOP 'program terminated by assert_eqn'
    end if
    END FUNCTION assert_eqn
    !BL
    SUBROUTINE nrerror(string)
    CHARACTER(LEN=*), INTENT(IN) :: string
    write (*,*) 'nrerror: ',string
    STOP 'program terminated by nrerror'
    END SUBROUTINE nrerror
!BL
    FUNCTION outerprod_r(a,b)
    REAL(SP), DIMENSION(:), INTENT(IN) :: a,b
    REAL(SP), DIMENSION(size(a),size(b)) :: outerprod_r
    outerprod_r = spread(a,dim=2,ncopies=size(b)) * &
        spread(b,dim=1,ncopies=size(a))
    END FUNCTION outerprod_r
!BL
    FUNCTION outerprod_d(a,b)
    REAL(DP), DIMENSION(:), INTENT(IN) :: a,b
    REAL(DP), DIMENSION(size(a),size(b)) :: outerprod_d
    outerprod_d = spread(a,dim=2,ncopies=size(b)) * &
        spread(b,dim=1,ncopies=size(a))
    END FUNCTION outerprod_d
!BL
END MODULE nrutil

MODULE nr
        INTERFACE pythag
        FUNCTION pythag_dp(a,b)
        USE nrtype
        REAL(DP), INTENT(IN) :: a,b
        REAL(DP) :: pythag_dp
        END FUNCTION pythag_dp
!BL
        FUNCTION pythag_sp(a,b)
        USE nrtype
        REAL(SP), INTENT(IN) :: a,b
        REAL(SP) :: pythag_sp
        END FUNCTION pythag_sp
    END INTERFACE
END MODULE nr


SUBROUTINE svdcmp_dp(a,w,v)
    USE nrtype; USE nrutil, ONLY : assert_eq,nrerror,outerprod
    USE nr, ONLY : pythag
    IMPLICIT NONE
    REAL(DP), DIMENSION(:,:), INTENT(INOUT) :: a
    REAL(DP), DIMENSION(:), INTENT(OUT) :: w
    REAL(DP), DIMENSION(:,:), INTENT(OUT) :: v
    INTEGER(I4B) :: i,its,j,k,l,m,n,nm
    REAL(DP) :: anorm,c,f,g,h,s,scale,x,y,z
    REAL(DP), DIMENSION(size(a,1)) :: tempm
    REAL(DP), DIMENSION(size(a,2)) :: rv1,tempn
    m=size(a,1)
    write(*,*)"size(a,1)= ",size(a,1)
    write(*,*)"size(a,2)= ",size(a,2)
    write(*,*)"size(v,1)= ",size(v,1)
    write(*,*)"size(v,2)= ",size(v,2)
    write(*,*)"size(w)  = ",size(w)
    n=assert_eq(size(a,2),size(v,1),size(v,2),size(w),'svdcmp_dp')
    g=0.0
    scale=0.0
    do i=1,n
        l=i+1
        rv1(i)=scale*g
        g=0.0
        scale=0.0
        if (i <= m) then
            scale=sum(abs(a(i:m,i)))
            if (scale /= 0.0) then
                a(i:m,i)=a(i:m,i)/scale
                s=dot_product(a(i:m,i),a(i:m,i))
                f=a(i,i)
                g=-sign(sqrt(s),f)
                h=f*g-s
                a(i,i)=f-g
                tempn(l:n)=matmul(a(i:m,i),a(i:m,l:n))/h
                a(i:m,l:n)=a(i:m,l:n)+outerprod(a(i:m,i),tempn(l:n))
                a(i:m,i)=scale*a(i:m,i)
            end if
        end if
        w(i)=scale*g
        g=0.0
        scale=0.0
        if ((i <= m) .and. (i /= n)) then
            scale=sum(abs(a(i,l:n)))
            if (scale /= 0.0) then
                a(i,l:n)=a(i,l:n)/scale
                s=dot_product(a(i,l:n),a(i,l:n))
                f=a(i,l)
                g=-sign(sqrt(s),f)
                h=f*g-s
                a(i,l)=f-g
                rv1(l:n)=a(i,l:n)/h
                tempm(l:m)=matmul(a(l:m,l:n),a(i,l:n))
                a(l:m,l:n)=a(l:m,l:n)+outerprod(tempm(l:m),rv1(l:n))
                a(i,l:n)=scale*a(i,l:n)
            end if
        end if
    end do
    anorm=maxval(abs(w)+abs(rv1))
    do i=n,1,-1
        if (i < n) then
            if (g /= 0.0) then
                v(l:n,i)=(a(i,l:n)/a(i,l))/g
                tempn(l:n)=matmul(a(i,l:n),v(l:n,l:n))
                v(l:n,l:n)=v(l:n,l:n)+outerprod(v(l:n,i),tempn(l:n))
            end if
            v(i,l:n)=0.0
            v(l:n,i)=0.0
        end if
        v(i,i)=1.0
        g=rv1(i)
        l=i
    end do
    do i=min(m,n),1,-1
        l=i+1
        g=w(i)
        a(i,l:n)=0.0
        if (g /= 0.0) then
            g=1.0_dp/g
            tempn(l:n)=(matmul(a(l:m,i),a(l:m,l:n))/a(i,i))*g
            a(i:m,l:n)=a(i:m,l:n)+outerprod(a(i:m,i),tempn(l:n))
            a(i:m,i)=a(i:m,i)*g
        else
            a(i:m,i)=0.0
        end if
        a(i,i)=a(i,i)+1.0_dp
    end do
    do k=n,1,-1
        do its=1,30
            do l=k,1,-1
                nm=l-1
                if ((abs(rv1(l))+anorm) == anorm) exit
                if ((abs(w(nm))+anorm) == anorm) then
                    c=0.0
                    s=1.0
                    do i=l,k
                        f=s*rv1(i)
                        rv1(i)=c*rv1(i)
                        if ((abs(f)+anorm) == anorm) exit
                        g=w(i)
                        h=pythag(f,g)
                        w(i)=h
                        h=1.0_dp/h
                        c= (g*h)
                        s=-(f*h)
                        tempm(1:m)=a(1:m,nm)
                        a(1:m,nm)=a(1:m,nm)*c+a(1:m,i)*s
                        a(1:m,i)=-tempm(1:m)*s+a(1:m,i)*c
                    end do
                    exit
                end if
            end do
            z=w(k)
            if (l == k) then
                if (z < 0.0) then
                    w(k)=-z
                    v(1:n,k)=-v(1:n,k)
                end if
                exit
            end if
            if (its == 30) call nrerror('svdcmp_dp: no convergence in svdcmp')
            x=w(l)
            nm=k-1
            y=w(nm)
            g=rv1(nm)
            h=rv1(k)
            f=((y-z)*(y+z)+(g-h)*(g+h))/(2.0_dp*h*y)
            g=pythag(f,1.0_dp)
            f=((x-z)*(x+z)+h*((y/(f+sign(g,f)))-h))/x
            c=1.0
            s=1.0
            do j=l,nm
                i=j+1
                g=rv1(i)
                y=w(i)
                h=s*g
                g=c*g
                z=pythag(f,h)
                rv1(j)=z
                c=f/z
                s=h/z
                f= (x*c)+(g*s)
                g=-(x*s)+(g*c)
                h=y*s
                y=y*c
                tempn(1:n)=v(1:n,j)
                v(1:n,j)=v(1:n,j)*c+v(1:n,i)*s
                v(1:n,i)=-tempn(1:n)*s+v(1:n,i)*c
                z=pythag(f,h)
                w(j)=z
                if (z /= 0.0) then
                    z=1.0_dp/z
                    c=f*z
                    s=h*z
                end if
                f= (c*g)+(s*y)
                x=-(s*g)+(c*y)
                tempm(1:m)=a(1:m,j)
                a(1:m,j)=a(1:m,j)*c+a(1:m,i)*s
                a(1:m,i)=-tempm(1:m)*s+a(1:m,i)*c
            end do
            rv1(l)=0.0
            rv1(k)=f
            w(k)=x
        end do
    end do
END SUBROUTINE svdcmp_dp
```

Note that I include only the portions of the modules that I need (just for this case). then, I compile this into a shared library like:

```
gfortran -shared -fPIC svdcmp_dp.f90 -o svdcmp_dp.so
```

so far, so good.

The next thing I do is in Julia:

```
julia> M=5
julia> a=rand(M,M) #just to see if it works
julia> v=zeros(M,M)
julia> w=zeros(M)
julia> t=ccall((:svdcmp_dp_, "./svdcmp_dp.so")
       , Void
       , ( Ref{Float64} # array a(mp,np)
        ,  Ref{Float64} # array w
        ,  Ref{Float64} # array v
       ) 
       ,a,w,v)
```

and I get:

```
julia> t=ccall((:svdcmp_dp_, "./svdcmp_dp.so")
       , Void
       , ( Ref{Float64} # array a(mp,np)
        ,  Ref{Float64} # array w
        ,  Ref{Float64} # array v
       ) 
       ,a,w,v)
 size(a,1)=            0
 size(a,2)=            0
 size(v,1)=            1
 size(v,2)=            1
 size(w)  =            1
 nrerror: an assert_eq failed with this tag:svdcmp_dp
STOP program terminated by assert_eq4
```

So, actually, my calling is OK, but apparently, the `size` intrinsic from Fortran 90 is NOT returning what I would expect. I say this because the first line in `svdcmp_dp.f90` is calling the function `assert_eq4` and determine that the dimensions are not compatible. This is not supposed to happen as I chose a[5 X 5], w[5], v[5,5], right?

I search about `size` in F90, and find out this:

Description:

```
Determine the extent of ARRAY along a specified dimension DIM, or the total number of elements in ARRAY if DIM is absent.

    Standard:
    Fortran 95 and later, with KIND argument Fortran 2003 and later

    Class:
    Inquiry function

    Syntax:
    RESULT = SIZE(ARRAY[, DIM [, KIND]])

    Arguments:
    ARRAY   Shall be an array of any type. If ARRAY is a pointer 
    it must be associated and allocatable arrays must be allocated.
    DIM (Optional) shall be a scalar of type INTEGER and its value shall 
    be in the range from 1 to n, where n equals the rank of ARRAY.
    KIND    (Optional) An INTEGER initialization expression indicating the 
    kind parameter of the result.
```

So, my guess is that the problem is related with the `allocable` property of `a,v` & `w`. Or the `pointer` issue (zero experience with pointers!)

Comment: @VladimirF I think I did. thanks anyways!

Comment: @VladimirF , much appreciated!

Comment: I'm curious what `svdcmp` offers that our `svd`/`svdfact` doesn't. Our `svd` is based on LAPACK which is the state of the art in numerical linear algebra.

Comment: @AndreasNoack Right!, svd from Julia is, indeed a very nice tool. Just that I am trying to translate (almost line by line, which is not very convenient..) a long F77 code to Julia, as a part of a big project. So, I need to translate all the subroutines in it to achieve the exact same result. This includes svdcmp, random subroutines, etc. Once I have finished, I will be certain that my code is properly translated, and then I will be able to replace all the translated functions to simple intrinsic ones (like: rand(), svdfact(), norm(), and so on...). It hasn't been a pleasant work so far...

Comment: @AndreasNoack I think it was a nice example on how to call a fortran subroutine, with multiple IN, OUT, INOUT arguments, from Julia, though!,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have actually solve this issue by replacing the declarations from:

```
SUBROUTINE svdcmp_dp(a,w,v)
    USE nrtype; USE nrutil, ONLY : assert_eq,nrerror,outerprod
    USE nr, ONLY : pythag
    IMPLICIT NONE
    REAL(DP), DIMENSION(:,:), INTENT(INOUT) :: a
    REAL(DP), DIMENSION(:), INTENT(OUT) :: w
    REAL(DP), DIMENSION(:,:), INTENT(OUT) :: v
    INTEGER(I4B) :: i,its,j,k,l,m,n,nm
    REAL(DP) :: anorm,c,f,g,h,s,scale,x,y,z
    REAL(DP), DIMENSION(size(a,1)) :: tempm
    REAL(DP), DIMENSION(size(a,2)) :: rv1,tempn
    m=size(a,1)
```

to :

```
SUBROUTINE svdcmp_dp(Ma,Na,a,w,v)
            USE nrtype; USE nrutil, ONLY : assert_eq,nrerror,outerprod
            USE nr, ONLY : pythag
            IMPLICIT NONE
            INTEGER(I4B) :: i,its,j,k,l,Ma,Na,m,n,nm

            REAL(DP), DIMENSION(Ma,Na), INTENT(INOUT) :: a
            REAL(DP), DIMENSION(Na), INTENT(INOUT) :: w
            REAL(DP), DIMENSION(Na,Na), INTENT(INOUT) :: v

            REAL(DP) :: anorm,c,f,g,h,s,scale,x,y,z
            REAL(DP), DIMENSION(size(a,1)) :: tempm
            REAL(DP), DIMENSION(size(a,2)) :: rv1,tempn
```

Note that the last one also incudes the dimentions of the input arrays!

PD:
Also, the code need the module(it was incomplete):

```
MODULE nr
    INTERFACE pythag
          MODULE PROCEDURE pythag_dp, pythag_sp
    END INTERFACE
CONTAINS

    FUNCTION pythag_dp(a,b)
        USE nrtype
        IMPLICIT NONE
        REAL(DP), INTENT(IN) :: a,b
        REAL(DP) :: pythag_dp
        REAL(DP) :: absa,absb
        absa=abs(a)
        absb=abs(b)
        if (absa > absb) then
            pythag_dp=absa*sqrt(1.0_dp+(absb/absa)**2)
        else
            if (absb == 0.0) then
                pythag_dp=0.0
            else
                pythag_dp=absb*sqrt(1.0_dp+(absa/absb)**2)
            end if
        end if
    END FUNCTION pythag_dp
!BL
    FUNCTION pythag_sp(a,b)
        USE nrtype
        IMPLICIT NONE
        REAL(SP), INTENT(IN) :: a,b
        REAL(SP) :: pythag_sp
        REAL(SP) :: absa,absb
        absa=abs(a)
        absb=abs(b)
            if (absa > absb) then
                pythag_sp=absa*sqrt(1.0_sp+(absb/absa)**2)
            else
                if (absb == 0.0) then
                    pythag_sp=0.0
                else
                    pythag_sp=absb*sqrt(1.0_sp+(absa/absb)**2)
                end if
            end if
    END FUNCTION pythag_sp

END MODULE nr
```

to run it(first, compile as a library):

```
julia> Na = 10;
julia> Ma = 10;
julia> w = zeros(Na);
julia> v = zeros(Na,Na);
julia> a = rand(Ma,Na);
julia> t = ccall((:svdcmp_dp_, "./svdcmp_dp.so")
              , Void
              , ( Ref{Int64}   # dim Ma
              ,   Ref{Int64}   # dim Na
              ,   Ref{Float64} # array a(Ma,Na)
               ,  Ref{Float64} # array w(Na)
               ,  Ref{Float64} # array v(Na,Na)
              ) 
              ,Ma,Na,a,w,v)
 size(a,1)=           10
 size(a,2)=           10
 size(v,1)=           10
 size(v,2)=           10
 size(w)  =           10

julia> a
10×10 Array{Float64,2}:
 -0.345725  -0.152634   -0.308378    0.16358    -0.0320809  …  -0.47387     0.429124    -0.45121   
 -0.262689   0.337605   -0.0870571   0.409442   -0.160302      -0.0551756   0.16718      0.612903  
 -0.269915   0.410518   -0.0546271  -0.251295   -0.465747       0.328763   -0.109375    -0.476041  
 -0.33862   -0.238028    0.3538     -0.110374    0.294611       0.052966    0.44796     -0.0296113 
 -0.327258  -0.432601   -0.250865    0.478916   -0.0284979      0.0839667  -0.557761    -0.0956028 
 -0.265429  -0.199584   -0.178273   -0.300575   -0.578186   …  -0.0561654   0.164844     0.35431   
 -0.333577   0.588873   -0.0587738   0.213815    0.349599       0.0573156   0.00210332  -0.0764212 
 -0.358586  -0.246824    0.211746    0.0193308   0.0844788      0.64333     0.105043     0.0645999 
 -0.340235   0.0145761  -0.344321   -0.602982    0.422866      -0.15449    -0.309766     0.220315  
 -0.301303   0.051581    0.712463   -0.0297202  -0.162096      -0.458565   -0.360566    -0.00623828

julia> w
10-element Array{Float64,1}:
 4.71084 
 1.47765 
 1.06096 
 0.911895
 0.123196
 0.235218
 0.418629
 0.611456
 0.722386
 0.688394

julia> v
10×10 Array{Float64,2}:
 -0.252394   0.128972   -0.0839656   0.6905     …   0.357651    0.0759095  -0.0858018  -0.111576 
 -0.222082  -0.202181   -0.0485353  -0.217066       0.11651    -0.223779    0.780065   -0.288588 
 -0.237793   0.109989    0.473947    0.155364       0.0821913  -0.61879     0.119753    0.33927  
 -0.343341  -0.439985   -0.459649   -0.233768       0.0948844  -0.155143   -0.233945    0.53929  
 -0.24665    0.0670331  -0.108927    0.119793      -0.520865    0.454486    0.375191    0.226854 
 -0.194316   0.301428    0.236947   -0.118114   …  -0.579563   -0.183961   -0.19942     0.0545692
 -0.349481  -0.61546     0.475366    0.227209      -0.0975147   0.274104   -0.0994582  -0.0834197
 -0.457956   0.349558    0.263727   -0.506634       0.418154    0.378996   -0.113577   -0.0262257
 -0.451763   0.0283005  -0.328583   -0.0121005     -0.219985   -0.276867   -0.269783   -0.604697 
 -0.27929    0.373724   -0.288427    0.246083       0.0529508   0.0369404   0.197368    0.265678
```

cheers!

Comment: Is this NR code or original code? The reason I ask is that I'm working on an open-source NR compatibility library to retain the original NR API/interface but wrap BLAS/LAPACK/etc. or (worst case) reimplement the functions; if this is a reimplementation, I may ask to use the code in my library. There are copyright issues in distributing NR code without a license and I want to provide an open-source migration path so legacy code can still be distributed while respecting the original NR copyrights. This gives developers some breathing room to refactor infringing NR code out of their projects.

Comment: @arclight This is a NR code (with a minor modification in the input arguments of the svdcmp subroutine). Also, I only copied the part of the modules that were used in this subroutines and disregard the rest. So it is basically a 99% NR subroutine...